# How to use where condition

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

can we dynamically appened where condition on a linq query?

for example:

```
class Result
{
      string v1;
      string v2;
      string v3;
}

List<Result> result = (from r in results select r);


//i want to do something like the following....

if(conditionA)
{
    result = result appened (or v1 = xxx)
}
else if(conditionB)
{
    result = result appened (or v2 = xxx)
}
else if(conditionC)
{
    result = result appened (or v3 == xxx)
}
```

Anyone know how handle the condition in Linq????

Th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `and` relationship of clauses, you can easily just append the `.Where()` filter method, as such:

```
where conditionOriginal(r) and conditionDynamic(r)
```

as

```
var results = (from r in originalResults
               where originalConditions(r)
               select r);
...
if (conditionA)
    results = results.Where(r => conditionDynamic(r));
```

To append an 'or' type relationship, however, you'd have to union with the original result set, like so:

```
where conditionOriginal(r) or conditionDynamic(r)
```

becomes

```
var results = (from r in originalResults
               where conditionOriginal(r)
               select r);
...
if (conditionB)
    results = results.Union((from r in originalResults
                             where conditionDynamic(r)
                             select r));
```

or

```
if (conditionB)
    results = results.Union(originalResults.Where(conditionDynamic(r)));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build it dynamically, you could use the 
[PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: +1 I have used PredicateBuilder for a Specification pattern with great success.

Answer (score 2):

Just append the `Where` query operator to your query :

```
if(conditionA)
{
    result = result.Where(r => r.v1 == xxx);
}
else if(conditionB)
{
    result = result.Where(r => r.v2 == xxx);
}
else if(conditionC)
{
    result = result.Where(r => r.v3 == xxx);
}
```

Note that your `results` variable should be declared as `IEnumerable<Result>`, not `List<Result>`

Comment: how about the relation ship..some is and some is or

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if (conditionA)
{
    result = result.Where(p => p.v1 == xxx); // Just guessing at the intent here.
}
// Repeat as necessary...
```

Or this:

```
if (conditionA)
{
    result = from r in result where p.v1 == xxx select r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Linq will delay execution, you can just append where to your query, and call tolist in the end to execute:

```
var query = from r in results;

//i want to do something like the following....

if(conditionA)
{
    query = result.Where(x => x.v1 = xxx);
}
else if(conditionB)
{
    query = result.Where(x => x.v2 = xxx);
}
else if(conditionC)
{
    query = result.Where(x => x.v1 = xxx);
}

List<Result> result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are the simplest solution. If you want a single execution you could also use expression trees:

http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2006/03/01/541179.aspx
http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Understanding-LINQ-Expression-Trees/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always call a function in the where clause, and build your condition there:

```
...
public bool MeetsConditions(Result r, bool a, bool b)
{
     bool result = false;
     if(a) result = result || r.v1==xxx
     if(b) result = result && r.v2==xxx
     return result;
}
...
var q = select from r in results where MeetsConditions(r, conditionA, conditionB)
```

Comment: but i need to dynamically create the condition...the "Result" is a sample..i will have lots of this kind of object